# fpc: PPU Source: [unit].pas not available

Tags: pascal, freepascal

I'm trying to compile the following minimal FreeVision program using     Free Pascal Compiler version 3.0.4 [2018/10/02] for x86_64 on macOs Mojave.

```
Program VeryShort;
Uses App;

Var MyProgram: TApplication;

Begin
    MyProgram.Init;
    MyProgram.Run;
    MyProgram.Done;
End.
```

However, I get the following error message:

```
$ fpc veryshort.p
Free Pascal Compiler version 3.0.4 [2018/10/02] for x86_64
Copyright (c) 1993-2017 by Florian Klaempfl and others
Target OS: Darwin for x86_64
Compiling veryshort.p
PPU Loading /usr/local/Cellar/fpc/3.0.4_1/lib/fpc/3.0.4/units/x86_64-darwin/fv/app.ppu
PPU Source: app.pas not available
PPU Source: platform.inc not available
Recompiling App, checksum changed for Menus
veryshort.p(2,6) Fatal: Can't find unit App used by VeryShort
Fatal: Compilation aborted
Error: /usr/local/bin/ppcx64 returned an error exitcode
```

The unit file `app.ppu` is found by the compiler, so I don't understand why it's trying to recompile it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the `-vut` options to the compiler, I found out that `fpc` picks up an incorrect unit as a dependency: there's a `menus.ppu` unit in two locations:

- `lib/fpc/3.0.4/units/x86_64-darwin/fv/menus.ppu`
- `lib/fpc/3.0.4/units/x86_64-darwin/univint/Menus.ppu`.

Unfortunately, `univint` is on the unit search path before `fv`, so the wrong unit is picked up.

I solved the issue by specifying the path to FreeVision explicitly on the command line: that way, FreeVision units are preferred while required `univint` units can still be found:

```
$ fpc -Fu/usr/local/lib/fpc/3.0.4/units/x86_64-darwin/fv veryshort.p
```

Note that there must *not* be a space between `-Fu` and the path. The path name may need to be adapted to the fpc version, target architecture and operating system.

Comment: Can't you use Lazarus? I guess the IDE would pick the right path names.

Comment: @joki this was the first thing that came into my mind: the fact that there is something fishy with the unit directory. Happens quite often in Turbo Pascal as well.

Comment: Afaik lazarus also simply uses a wildcard that recursively reads the unit directory. The solution is meant to be putting an extra -Fu with the desired directory first, but in the next major version, dotted unitnames might solve it

Comment: @Rudy Velthuis ironically, the first posts I found when searching for this problem were people running into similar issues while trying to compile Lazarus ;) I was surprised that fpc in its default install ships similarly named units which are picked up by default with no obvious error message

Comment: @Bogdan Doicin what made it difficult for me to diagnose was that there's no indication from which directories fpc loads the units and that the directories are traversed in apparently arbitrary (probably file system) order, so the results are different on each system :-\

Comment: @Marco van de Voort this sounds promising indeed, albeit not for compiling legacy software, which is what I'm trying to do here

Comment: @Joki: Hmmm... I  must admit I also had problems using it on the Mac, but that was quite a few years ago. I assumed such problems would be solved, by now. Currently the Mac is dead and I need a new one, so I had no way to check things on the Mac.